# Updating cordova-android@ in Visual Studio 2015 RTM

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

When I create a default Cordova TypeScript project, the project default is set to `cordova-android@4.0.2`.

I am using the latest version 4.1.0 and would like to have Visual Studio 2015 use 4.1.0 version as default.

Can I set the version of cordova-android in Visual Studio?

I would prefer not to update the cordova-android for each project using a command prompt.

Instructions on how to upgrade Cordova Android 4.1.0 using command prompt:
http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/07/21/cordova-android-4.1.0.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short version of what is described [in the docs here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/tree/master/tips-and-workarounds/general#cordova-platform-ver) is as follows:

In Visual Studio, right click on config.xml and select “View Code” and add the following under the root  element in config.xml

```
<engine name="android" spec="4.1.0" />
```

Next, for projects where you have already executed a build for the platform on your system, you’ll also need to remove the old version of the Cordova platform.

Open a command prompt and go to your Cordova project root (not the solution root) and type the following commands:

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova platform remove android
```

The next time you build you will now be on the updated version of the platform.

Note removing the platform is only required if you've built using the old platform version on your machine and is a one time thing if so.

Comment: Thanks for the link and taking the time to answer the question. Also, the `cordova platform remove android` is a huge help!  Here's an example where it helped: I created a Cordova project, added Crosswalk plugin, published the project (debug > android > device).  Realized I hadn't added `<engine name="android" spec="4.1.0" />` to config.xml and then added it. Published project and got a build error.  command prompt 'cordova platform remove android` project root.  Build Works!