# Visual Studio 2015 - Cordova - Build issue, cause vs-tac/app.js not found

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

**Versions**

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

VS TACO Update 10

TypeScript 2.4.1

**What i have done**

1. i set External tools to global nodejs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRqR8.jpg

2. i changed cordova cli from 6.3.1 to 6.5.0... using the article of the taco page.

3.i used cmd to navigate to the cordova project folder in my solution like "D:\Projects\XYZ\LM\LM.CordovaApp (LM.Cordova is project in VS2015 solution). then i try to update my cordova-android (it installed version6.2.3). i'm used the commands:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform install android
```

**Errors**

After Build:

```
MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD401: Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'D:\Projects\XYZ\LM\LM.CordovaApp\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
```

this is not exactly the same error like this "Could not find module ‘C:\Users{name}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js’. Please Go to Tools –> Options –> Tools for Apache Cordova –> Cordova Tools –> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again", **which i can find many solutions, but my error doesn't point to the global npm node_modules, it points to the node_modules of my project and in my global Roaming\npm\node_modules is a vs-tac directory.**

Clear Cordova Cache doesn't help.
Clear npm cache + Cordova Cache doesn't help.

after looked over this page "https://decoupledlogic.com/2016/05/11/fixed-error-building-cordova-in-visual-studio/", i had an idea... i add to my package.json of the project the dependency:

```
"vs-tac": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\ApacheCordovaTools\\Packages\\vs-tac"
```

now i restored package, rebuild and the error changed....to:

```
 BLD00401 : Could not find module 'elementtree'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.
```

but i can ses in my project node_modules the directory "elementtree"....

Clean Cordova Cache doesn't help.

no i'm out of ideas.

**have anyone a idea or solution??? how can update cordova-cli and cordova platforms of a Visual Studio Cordova Project correctly?**

actually i rolled back to cordova-cli 6.3.1 and the old platform versions...

Comment: to point 3... i followed: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/platform_plugin_versioning_ref/index.html
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726206/updating-cordova-android-in-visual-studio-2015-rtm

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: i haven't found a solution with VS2015. i changed to Visual Studio 2017 and actually i'm using Visual Studio Code